# Returning Response from TCP Inbound Gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I'm stuck on a seemingly simple task, but am out of ideas. I have a `TcpInboundGateway` attached to a `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` that passes requests to a Service Activator. The Service Activator simply puts the message back on the Gateway's reply channel. I want the Gateway to return that message over the connection.

When I run the test, the message makes it to the Service Activator successfully. I know this because the Service Activator prints the message payload before returning it. I also know the Service Activator is putting the message on the right channel because I have an interceptor on that channel which also prints the message.

The problem seems to be that the Gateway isn't reading off of that channel, even though I set it in `setReplyChannel()`. I can also see this in the logs:

```
Adding {bridge:null} as a subscriber to the 'testResponseChannel' channel
```

which makes me suspect that the message is just getting sent to the null channel instead of being picked up by my Gateway.

Here's the configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public TcpNetServerConnectionFactory testServerFactory() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory testServerFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(0);
        testServerFactory.setSerializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader2());
        testServerFactory.setDeserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader2());
        return testServerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel testRequestChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel testResponseChannel() {
        DirectChannel testResponseChannel = new DirectChannel();
        testResponseChannel.addInterceptor(channelInterceptor());
        return testResponseChannel;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpInboundGateway gateway() {
        TcpInboundGateway gateway = new TcpInboundGateway();
        gateway.setConnectionFactory(testServerFactory());
        gateway.setRequestChannel(testRequestChannel());
        gateway.setReplyChannel(testResponseChannel());
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "testRequestChannel", outputChannel = "testResponseChannel")
    public EchoHandler echoHandler() {
        return new EchoHandler();
    }
```

Here's my POJO Service Activator:

```
public class EchoHandler {

    public Message<String> echoMessage(Message<String> request) {
        System.out.println(request.getPayload());
        return request;
    }
}
```

And here's the error, which happens right after the message passes through the interceptor:

```
Unexpected message - no endpoint registered with connection interceptor: localhost:6060:59848:3c6c3cff-c697-4fc9-b4e3-9ea14508cec7 - GenericMessage [payload=byte[3], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6060, ip_connectionId=localhost:6060:59848:3c6c3cff-c697-4fc9-b4e3-9ea14508cec7, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=93c75664-54db-c93e-ab3a-3e06b1e4b626, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1556828832645}]
```

Comment: Isn't that a problem on the TCP client side? So, you use there a `TcpSendingMessageHandler`, but not `TcpOutboundGateway`. Any chances that we can have a simple project from you to play with and reproduce ?

Comment: Aha, you're right. I assumed the problem was with the server, but it was actually with the client. The server's gateway was sending the message back successfully, but the client didn't have a TcpListener to receive it.

Answer (score 1):

To react properly for the reply from the server, your client must be a request-response capable. For this purpose Spring Integration IP modules suggests a `TcpOutboundGateway`. This way a `TcpListener` is going to be registered on the `TcpConnection` and ready to parse and handle replies messages on the socket.